# SonarScanner not publishing results in SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube, asp.net-core-2.1, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I execute **SonarScanner** in a **.NET Core MVC** application whithout any errors but the **SonarQube** show any `Issue` or `Metric`, still empty/clean.

To start the SonarRunner I use the above .bat that point to sonarscanner .dll

```
dotnet "C:\Documents\sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.6.2.2108-netcoreapp2.0\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" begin /k:"TopFornecedores" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000/sonarqube" /d:sonar.login="a5491f467a70f572e2cc0415ca16207188addedc"

dotnet build "C:\ASP.NET\TopFornecedores\Codigo\TopFornecedores.sln"

dotnet "C:\Documents\sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.6.2.2108-netcoreapp2.0\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" end /d:sonar.login="a5491f467a70f572e2cc0415ca16207188addedc"
```

When I use the verbose output I have the final:

```
Writing processing summary to C:\ASP.NET\TopFornecedores\Codigo\.sonarqube\out\ProjectInfo.log
Calling the SonarQube Scanner...
Executing file C:\Users\Ricardo\Documents\sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.6.2.2108-netcoreapp2.0\sonar-scanner-3.3.0.1492\bin\sonar-scanner.bat
  Args: -Dsonar.scanAllFiles=true -Dproject.settings=C:\ASP.NET\TopFornecedores\Codigo\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties --embedded --debug <sensitive data removed>
  Working directory: C:\ASP.NET\TopFornecedores\Codigo
  Timeout (ms):-1
  Process id: 1724
Process returned exit code 0
The SonarQube Scanner has finished
18:24:24.338  Post-processing succeeded.
```

How I configure the **SonarQube**

[image: SonarQube Config]

Although it is written SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe I use .NET Core Pattern

To test all permissions are granted to all users and users group.

The .NET CORE solution has multiples projects: 1 with Controllers and Views (Razor .cshtml) (this project generate 2 .dll one with all .cs and another with views), 1 with models, 1 with logic both is class library and 1 is Test project (xUnit). (All with .Net Core 2.1)

In the Solution folder are generated a **.sonarqube** with multiples sub folders **bin, conf, out** in **conf** and **out** has folder like **0,1,2,3...** in out has **output-cs** with many files.

I configure the **sonar.properties** (inside SonarQube folder) with above parameters:

```
sonar.jdbc.username=SonarRoot
sonar.jdbc.password=SonarSenha
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor;instance=sqlexpress 
sonar.web.javaOpts=-server -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1 
sonar.web.context=/sonarqube
sonar.web.port=9000
```

and configure the **sonar-scanner.properties** (inside SonarScanner folder) with:

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/sonarqube
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

I run SonarQube with `StartSonar.bat` not as windows service.
After I check some tables (`ce_queue`, `ce_activity`) in database and were empty.
The only change made in Solution/Projects is the include a Tag `SonarQubeTestProject` in Test Project.

**My Target Framework:**

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

**Edit:**
I make another test, I create a solution with 2 projects, first is console and second is class library, both with some anti-patterns (like unused mehtod) and again nothing is reported in `SonarQube`

**Logs:**
[access.log](https://pastebin.com/4Xq8pn4G)
[ce.log](https://pastebin.com/vZMZ694Q)
[es.log](https://pastebin.com/Ez44n7eF)
[sonar.log](https://pastebin.com/tNJscNNm)
[web.log](https://pastebin.com/DzRrPADB)

**Environment:**
SonarQube: 7.9.1 LTS 
SonarScanner: sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.6.2.2108-netcoreapp2.0 
.NET Application: .NET Core 2.1 (ASP.NET MVC) 
OS: Windows 10 
JAVA: jdk-12.0.2

Comment: Any errors/activity in the SonarQube logs?

Comment: @JeroenHeier no any error/exception is reported in logs.

Comment: Which edition of SonarQube are you using (Community/Developer/Enterprise)? Also. the paths in the "dotnet build" and "Writing processing summary to..." don't match: one has "SUPERDEV" in the path, the other doesn't. Is that correct?

Comment: Community Edition, the path in some place are truncated for brevity